# PDF not showing jpeg images in flutter

Tags: flutter, pdf, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Images are stored in sqflite database in the form of base64 encoded. Png images are showing perfectly using this code.
[From here](https://shriya-apps.medium.com/asset-image-inside-the-pdf-in-flutter-dart-da2ce4746e94)

```
   try {

bytes = base64.decode(<base64 Image String>);

image = PdfImage.file(

pdf.document,

bytes: bytes,

);

} catch (e) {

bytes = null;

image = null;

}
```

But not working for jpeg base64 encoded images.

[image: jpeg image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This blog post has it wrong.

Here is a better example:
https://gist.github.com/DavBfr/a70e763582e95f70331d14ad03ddfe7d